# How to set an HTTP header for a JSON message from within a django-piston handler?

Tags: django, django-piston

In a piston handler, I need to return a django.db.models.query.QuerySet as a proper JSON message (reflective of the underly model and query), while also adding an HttpResponse header of my own. So far, I can do one or the other, but not both (and get a proper looking JSON response).

The below generates a proper JSON formatted response, but with no added HttpResponse header (not shown):

```
class PollHandlerSearch(BaseHandler):
    allowed_methods = ('POST')
    model = Poll
    fields = ('id', 'question', 'pub_date')
    KEYS =  ( 'question', 'start-date', 'end-date' )

    def create(self, request):
        post = Poll.objects.all()
        for skey in self.KEYS:
            if len(post) and request.POST.has_key(skey) and len(request.POST[skey]):
                if skey == self.KEYS[0]:
                        post = post.filter(question__icontains=request.POST[skey])
                elif skey == self.KEYS[1]:
                        post = post.filter(pub_date__gte=request.POST[skey])
                elif skey == self.KEYS[2]:
                        post = post.filter(pub_date__lte=request.POST[skey])
        return post
```

Resulting correctly formatted JSON message:

```
[
    {
        "pub_date": "2010-08-23 22:15:07", 
        "question": "What's up?", 
        "id": 1
    }
]
```

The below implements an HttpResponse with the added header and generates a JSONish looking response, but one that is not what is being expected or wanted, plus not reflecting whatever django's 'DateTimeAwareJSONEncoder' does (used by piston's JSONEmitter).

```
class PollHandlerSearch(BaseHandler):
    allowed_methods = ('POST')
    model = Poll
    fields = ('id', 'question', 'pub_date')
    KEYS =  ( 'question', 'start-date', 'end-date' )

    def create(self, request):
        resp = HttpResponse()
        post = Poll.objects.all()
        for skey in self.KEYS:
            if len(post) and request.POST.has_key(skey) and len(request.POST[skey]):
                if skey == self.KEYS[0]:
                        post = post.filter(question__icontains=request.POST[skey])
                elif skey == self.KEYS[1]:
                        post = post.filter(pub_date__gte=request.POST[skey])
                elif skey == self.KEYS[2]:
                        post = post.filter(pub_date__lte=request.POST[skey])
        json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
        json_serializer.serialize(post, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, stream=resp)
        resp['MYHEADER'] = 'abc123'
        return resp
```

Resulting incorrectly formatted JSONish message:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1, 
        "model": "polls.poll", 
        "fields": {
            "pub_date": "2010-08-23 22:15:07", 
            "question": "What's up?"
        }
    }
]
```

This is no doubt happening since I am doing my own JSON serialization, bypassing piston's JSONEmitter and thus whatever it does to properly render 'post'.

I have been pouring over piston's emitters.py, and largely can't follow it (I am pretty new at OOP / Python / django / piston). How can I get piston to deliver a properly formatted JSON message with an HTTP header supplemented with headers I provide?

Answer (score 3):

You could subclass `piston.resource.Resource`, and add whatever header you want in the `__call__` method.
    from piston.resource import Resource

```
class MyResource(Resource):
    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        resp = super(MyResource, self).__call__(request, *args, **kwargs)
        resp['HEADER'] = "abc123"
        return resp
```

Then, in your urls.py:

```
def BasicResource(handler):
    return resource.MyResource(handler=handler, authentication=basic)

your_handler = BasicResource(YourHandlerClass)
another_handler = BasicResource(AnotherHandlerClass)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The way Piston creates a new response object in `Resource.__call__` makes it a bit hard to cleanly get response headers from a handler out to the client. I setup a hack of a pattern in my app whereby I set an attribute on the request object and then read it after calling `__call__`.

`if hasattr(request, 'num_objects'):
    response['X-EB-Num-Objects'] = request.num_objects`

Not my finest work.

Comment: @BobVanZant: I got things working that way too. Annoying and ugly, but works... like most things Piston.